# Can we insert multiple rows into a table using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

1. T_Order (OrderID)
2. T_Item (ItemID)

In `T_Order` table I have the `ItemID` as FK.

Is it possible to store multiple ItemIDs in one OrderID using a stored procedure?

For example:

- OrderID 1 has ItemID 1,2,5

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a little-known way to upload a list as a single stored procedure parameter and make it work without multiple calls. There's a bit of setup required.

First, you have to define a SQL type that can contain your list:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyList
AS TABLE
(
    ID VarChar(50)
);
```

Then, write a stored procedure that accepts this type as its input parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertOrderItems
    @OrderID int, @ItemList AS dbo.MyList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo][Orders] 
    SELECT @OrderID

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderItems] 
    SELECT @OrderID, ID FROM @ItemList
END
```

Now to bind your data to the stored procedure from the c# end. To bind it, you have to store the data in a `DataTable` first, which is relatively easy:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
foreach (var itemID item in order.Items)
{
    table.Rows.Add(itemID);
}
```

Then submit the table to the stored procedure like so:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand()
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = "InsertOrderItems",
        Connection = myConnection
    };
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OrderID", order.ID);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ItemList", SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        TypeName = "dbo.MyList",
        Value = table
    });
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting multiple ItemID would be no problem. The question is, how you would like to get the ItemIds to your stored procedure. There is the possibility to use XML or a list separated with commas, but both options aren't really "recommended" as it complicates things. The best solution would be to solve this in the application and not database logic.